# I am trying to run an mssql stored view through php but get an error, stored procedures work fine but the view fails

Tags: php, sql-server

I have the following view run to an external mssql database. I am connecting to the same database for some full stored procedures with input parameters and these work fine but the view doesnt work and gives the error

```
Warning: mssql_execute() [function.mssql-execute]: message: The request for procedure 'usv_Extended_Confirmation' failed because 'usv_Extended_Confirmation' is a view object. (severity 18) in 

Warning: mssql_execute() [function.mssql-execute]: General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server (severity 18) in 

Warning: mssql_execute() [function.mssql-execute]: stored procedure execution failed in

Warning: mssql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in
```

The script calling the view is as follows

```
//run msdb connected view procedure
function runView($procedure){
    global $msdb;

    //initiate function
    $proc = mssql_init('usv_Extended_Confirmation', $msdb); 

    //Execute Procedure 
    $result = mssql_execute($proc); 

    while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        $results[] = $row;    
        }
    $return = $results;

    //Free Memory 
    mssql_free_statement($proc); 

    return $return;
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to execute a view? Did you try `SELECT cols FROM viewname`?

Comment: figured it was something simple, thanks all. will accept when it allows me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't execute a view. A view is like table or a query - you `Select` from it.

```
$query = mssql_query('SELECT * FROM usv_Extended_Confirmation');
while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    ....
```

Answer (score 1):

since it's a VIEW shouldn't you be calling it from a SELECT statement

```
SELECT * FROM usv_Extended_Confirmation
```

Comment: can u give me a converted example based on the syntax above? I've been trying to find the syntax for it

Comment: $result= mssql_query('SELECT * FROM usv_Extended_Confirmation');